# Difference between Canvas.concat() and Canvas.setMatrix()?

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas

Documents in about `Canvas.setMatrix()` say:

> Completely replace the current matrix with the specified matrix. If
>   the matrix parameter is null, then the current matrix is reset to
>   identity.

And about `Canvas.concat()` say:

> Preconcat the current matrix with the specified matrix.

But It seems surd.When I tried this code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
mCamera = new Camera();
canvas.save();

mCamera.rotateY(y_rotate_angle);
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
canvas.concat(matrix);
canvas.drawText(text, 30, 100, redPaint);

//      canvas.restore();
canvas.setMatrix(null);
canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
canvas.drawText(text, 30, 100, greenPaint);
```

In result,second text will drawn at (60,100) **instead** of drawing at (30,100)(even when I tried `canvas.restore()` and comment `canvas.setMatrix`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange!I get matrix of canvas before saving it and then print it's members.I guessed that it be `IDENTITY` matrix,but it was not!So when I did `setMatrix(null)`,the matrix of canvas was set by a matrix that was not equal to original matrix of canvas and this caused problems.